# How to allow only English submissions on Pligg CMS

Tags: content-management-system, pligg

I have got a client requirement where he is using Pligg CMS for social bookmarking. He is getting a lot of manual spam entries in multiple languages. Does Pligg has any setting or Plugin where we can allow only English entries. If any one can suggest a good alternative to Pligg will also help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the spam trigger module (included with Pligg) and add the following to one of the Trigger configuration fields from the settings page.

```
À
Á
Â
Ã
Ä
Å
Æ
Ā
Ą
Ă
Ç
Ć
Č
Ĉ
Ċ
Ď
Đ
È
É
Ê
Ë
Ē
Ę
Ě
Ĕ
Ė
Ĝ
Ğ
Ġ
Ģ
Ĥ
Ħ
Ì
Í
Î
Ï
Ī
Ĩ
Ĭ
Į
İ
Ĳ
Ĵ
Ķ
Ľ
Ĺ
Ļ
Ŀ
Ł
Ñ
Ń
Ň
Ņ
Ŋ
Ò
Ó
Ô
Õ
Ö
Ø
Ō
Ő
Ŏ
Œ
Ŕ
Ř
Ŗ
Ś
Ş
Ŝ
Ș
Š
Ť
Ţ
Ŧ
Ț
Ù
Ú
Û
Ü
Ū
Ů
Ű
Ŭ
Ũ
Ų
Ŵ
Ŷ
Ÿ
Ý
Ź
Ż
Ž
à
á
â
ã
ä
ā
ą
ă
å
æ
ç
ć
č
ĉ
ċ
ď
đ
è
é
ê
ë
ē
ę
ě
ĕ
ė
ƒ
ĝ
ğ
ġ
ģ
ĥ
ħ
ì
í
î
ï
ī
ĩ
ĭ
į
ı
ĳ
ĵ
ķ
ĸ
ł
ľ
ĺ
ļ
ŀ
ñ
ń
ň
ņ
ŉ
ŋ
ò
ó
ô
õ
ö
ø
ō
ő
ŏ
œ
ŕ
ř
ŗ
ś
š
ş
ť
ţ
ù
ú
û
ü
ū
ů
ű
ŭ
ũ
ų
ụ
ŵ
ÿ
ý
ŷ
ż
ź
ž
ß
ſ
Α
Ά
Ἀ
Ἁ
Ἂ
Ἃ
Ἄ
Ἅ
Ἆ
Ἇ
ᾈ
ᾉ
ᾊ
ᾋ
ᾌ
ᾍ
ᾎ
ᾏ
Ᾰ
Ᾱ
Ὰ
Ά
ᾼ
Β
Γ
Δ
Ε
Έ
Ἐ
Ἑ
Ἒ
Ἓ
Ἔ
Ἕ
Έ
Ὲ
Ζ
Η
Ή
Ἠ
Ἡ
Ἢ
Ἣ
Ἤ
Ἥ
Ἦ
Ἧ
ᾘ
ᾙ
ᾚ
ᾛ
ᾜ
ᾝ
ᾞ
ᾟ
Ὴ
Ή
ῌ
Θ
Ι
Ί
Ϊ
Ἰ
Ἱ
Ἲ
Ἳ
Ἴ
Ἵ
Ἶ
Ἷ
Ῐ
Ῑ
Ὶ
Ί
Κ
Λ
Μ
Ν
Ξ
Ο
Ό
Ὀ
Ὁ
Ὂ
Ὃ
Ὄ
Ὅ
Ὸ
Ό
Π
Ρ
Ῥ
Σ
Τ
Υ
Ύ
Ϋ
Ὑ
Ὓ
Ὕ
Ὗ
Ῠ
Ῡ
Ὺ
Ύ
Φ
Χ
Ψ
Ω
Ώ
Ὠ
Ὡ
Ὢ
Ὣ
Ὤ
Ὥ
Ὦ
Ὧ
ᾨ
ᾩ
ᾪ
ᾫ
ᾬ
ᾭ
ᾮ
ᾯ
Ὼ
Ώ
ῼ
α
ά
ἀ
ἁ
ἂ
ἃ
ἄ
ἅ
ἆ
ἇ
ᾀ
ᾁ
ᾂ
ᾃ
ᾄ
ᾅ
ᾆ
ᾇ
ὰ
ά
ᾰ
ᾱ
ᾲ
ᾳ
ᾴ
ᾶ
ᾷ
β
γ
δ
ε
έ
ἐ
ἑ
ἒ
ἓ
ἔ
ἕ
ὲ
έ
ζ
η
ή
ἠ
ἡ
ἢ
ἣ
ἤ
ἥ
ἦ
ἧ
ᾐ
ᾑ
ᾒ
ᾓ
ᾔ
ᾕ
ᾖ
ᾗ
ὴ
ή
ῂ
ῃ
ῄ
ῆ
ῇ
θ
ι
ί
ϊ
ΐ
ἰ
ἱ
ἲ
ἳ
ἴ
ἵ
ἶ
ἷ
ὶ
ί
ῐ
ῑ
ῒ
ΐ
ῖ
ῗ
κ
λ
μ
ν
ξ
ο
ό
ὀ
ὁ
ὂ
ὃ
ὄ
ὅ
ὸ
ό
π
ρ
ῤ
ῥ
σ
ς
τ
υ
ύ
ϋ
ΰ
ὐ
ὑ
ὒ
ὓ
ὔ
ὕ
ὖ
ὗ
ὺ
ύ
ῠ
ῡ
ῢ
ΰ
ῦ
ῧ
φ
χ
ψ
ω
ώ
ὠ
ὡ
ὢ
ὣ
ὤ
ὥ
ὦ
ὧ
ᾠ
ᾡ
ᾢ
ᾣ
ᾤ
ᾥ
ᾦ
ᾧ
ὼ
ώ
ῲ
ῳ
ῴ
ῶ
ῷ
¨
΅
᾿
῾
῍
῝
῎
῞
῏
῟
῀
῁
΄
΅
`
῭
ͺ
᾽
А
Б
В
Г
Д
Е
Ё
Ж
З
И
Й
К
Л
М
Н
О
П
Р
С
Т
У
Ф
Х
Ц
Ч
Ш
Щ
Ы
Э
Ю
Я
а
б
в
г
д
е
ё
ж
з
и
й
к
л
м
н
о
п
р
с
т
у
ф
х
ц
ч
ш
щ
ы
э
ю
я
Ъ
ъ
Ь
ь
ð
Ð
þ
Þ
Ề
ề
Ể
ể
Ễ
ễ
Ế
ế
Ệ
ệ
Ộ
ộ
Ơ
ơ
Ư
ư
ờ
ა
ბ
გ
დ
ე
ვ
ზ
თ
ი
კ
ლ
მ
ნ
ო
პ
ჟ
რ
ს
ტ
უ
ფ
ქ
ღ
ყ
შ
ჩ
ც
ძ
წ
ჭ
ხ
ჯ
ჰ
ב
ג
ד
ה
ו
ז
ח
ט
י
כ
ל
מ
נ
ס
פ
צ
ק
ר
ש
ת
ա
բ
գ
դ
ե
զ
է
ը
թ
ժ
ի
լ
խ
ծ
կ
հ
ձ
ղ
ճ
մ
յ
ն
շ
ո
չ
պ
ջ
ռ
ս
վ
տ
ր
ց
ւ
փ
ք
օ
ֆ
և
```

This list is made up of many non-English characters, so it will flag any posts that use these letters. I pulled this list from Pligg's /languages/translit.txt file, which is used to transcribe these letters into more common English ones for use in URLs. It's not complete, for example it does not have any Asian language characters.